# Автовысота textarea при формировании страницы

Tags: html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как при формировании страницы выставить автовысоту textarea?
Формирую страницу в PHP (из базы естественно), загоняю текст в textarea. Теста может быть не много, а может быть на десяток строк.
Начальные размеры textarea 200 на 25 px - один из элемент номера телефонов (тип text, их может быть несколько), адрес проживания (тип text, он может быть весьма длинным), и еще несколько подобных.

Answer (score 2):

С текстареа тот еще геморрой будет.

Возможно, вам поможет ячейка таблицы, которая ведет себя так, как вам нужно, и которой добавлены атрибут/стиля для возможности редактирования содержимого:

```css
td {
border:1px solid;
-webkit-user-modify: read-write;
-moz-user-modify: read-write;
-ms-user-modify: read-write;
user-modify: read-write;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td contenteditable="true">
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для большей простоты можно использовать плагин - [jquery Autosize](https://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/). Тогда высота будет настраиваться автоматически при: вставке первоначального динамического текста, печати нового, или его удалении. Ширину textarea можно регулировать атрибутом cols="значение-в-символах", например cols="80" означает ширину для textarea в 80 символов. Высоту отрегулирует сам плагин.
Инициализировать в js можно так:

```
autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));
```

Рабочий пример можно глянуть ниже:

```js
autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autosize@4.0.2/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="80">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>
```